# Array not updating when using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to splice an array in order to delete an object from my array. I'm using angular-formly to display the forms and AngularJs and JQuery in order to handle the data.

**The JQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete-me", function () {
    var id = $(this).parent().find('input, select, textarea').attr('id');
    var splitid = id.split("_")[3];
    angular.element(document.getElementById('View2Ctrl')).scope().removeField(splitid);
    $(this).closest('.formly-field').remove();
});
```

The reason for the split and is that formly wraps an id like *formly_1_input_textField-1_0*.

**The Angular Function**

```
 $scope.removeField = function (id) {
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.formFields.length;i++){

            if($scope.formFields[i].key == id){

                $scope.formFields.splice(id, 1);

                console.log($scope.formFields.length);

                $scope.currentId = i;
            }
        }
    };
```

The console log is displaying the actual length of the array however I have {{formFields.length}} on the template and it does not update, as well as {{formFields}} still showing the data in the array. I suspect that JQuery updating the DOM isn't being watched by Angular and have tried calling $scope.$apply() manually to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of logic errors in your function:

1. When you remove an item from the array, you increase `i` anyway, which means you'll miss out the next item if it's a match.
2. You're using `id` instead of `i` in the `splice`

That second one is probably the culprit, but once you'd fixed that, the first would have bitten you (unless the `id` values are unique, as the name implies; in which case, you should probably terminate the loop when you find it).

Updates:

```
$scope.removeField = function (id) {
    var i=0;
    while (i<$scope.formFields.length){          // Use a while loop

        if($scope.formFields[i].key == id){

            $scope.formFields.splice(i, 1);      // Use i, not id

            console.log($scope.formFields.length);

            $scope.currentId = i;

            // DON'T increment i here, you've removed the element

            // Or if IDs are unique, just terminate the loop
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: That seemed to make it work when deleting starting at the last object in the array but not if I delete the first object or any other object first. Any ideas ?

Comment: @adamPower: From a straightforward "removing things from an array" perspective, the above should work. I can't comment on the angular parts of it; I haven't worked with angular.